# bash script pulling variables from .txt, keeps giving syntax error while trying to use mount command

Tags: bash, sh

Ive been trying to get this to work for the last week and cannot figure out why this is not working.  I get mixed results typing directly into the terminal, but keep getting syntax error messages when running from the .sh.  using ubuntu 11.10

It looks like part of the mount command gets pushed to the next line not allowing it to complete properly.. I have no idea why this is happening or how to prevent it from going to the second line.

i have several lines defined as follows in mounts.txt, that gets read from mount-drives.sh below

I have called it to run using sudo so it shouldnt be a permissions issue.

Thanks for taking a look, let me know if additional info is needed.

mounts.txt

```
    mountname,//server/share$,username,password,
```

mount-drives.sh ---origional, updated below

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while read LINE;
    do 

    # split lines up using , to separate variables
    name=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 1)
    path=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 2)
    user=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 3)
    pass=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 4)

    echo $name
    echo $path
    echo $user
    echo $pass


    location="/mnt/test/$name/"

    if [ ! -d $location ]
    then
        mkdir $location
    fi

    otherstuff="-o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=$user,password=$pass"

    mount -t cifs $otherstuff $path $location

    done < "/path/to/mounts.txt";
```

mount-drives.sh ---updated

```
    #!/bin/bash

    while read LINE
    do
        name=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 1)
        path=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 2)
        user=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 3)
        pass=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 4)
        empty=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f 5)
        location="/mount/test/$name/"
        if [ ! -d $location ]
        then
            mkdir $location
        fi
        mounting="mount -t cifs $path $location -o username=$user,password=$pass,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777"
        $mounting
        echo $mounting >> test.txt
     done < "/var/www/MediaCenter/mounts.txt"
```

Comment: Try running your script with the '-x' option to have bash print out each line as it executes.  Either add 'set -x' near the top, or do `bash -x ./mount-drives.sh`.  I'm gonna guess the '$' in the .txt file is causing problems when you echo $LINE ...

Comment: thanks for something to look into, it doesnt appear the -x is working for me, or there is an error that prevents it from displaying.  I tried launching from terminal and using the set -x  command in the script with the same issue.  Am i supposed to escape the $LINE in the echo somehow?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to put double quotes around `$LINE` in the echo.  Does the script echo the correct values to the terminal?

Comment: Have you tried putting echo before the mount command, to see what is being executed?  If so, please post it.  You say part of the command is pushed onto the next line - which part?

Comment: it looks like the $LINE and the following echo $user etc are getting the correct variables.  when i copy everything into terminal, it goes through, but has an error with the mount command.  this is the output from an echo of the mount, it looks like it gets split at the "-o" in the output file, but when i copy it from the output file into the terminal it splits before $path:

mount -t cifs -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=username,password=password
 "//server/share$" /mnt/test/mount/

Comment: when i use double quotes around the $LINE it makes no difference, and i can pass the variables in both instances.

this is what copies into the terminal from the output.txt file:

first line:  "mount -t cifs -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=username,password=pas‌​sword"

and on the second line: " "//server/share$" /mnt/test/mount/"     NOTE: i added the outside double quotes for clarification

Comment: Can you try changing the line `echo $pass` to `echo "'$pass'"`?  That will print single quotes around the printing of the password, to see if it is including a newline

Comment: `while IFS=, read -r name path user pass empty` -  no need for all those `echo | cut` commands. Always quote variables when they are expanded.

Comment: Running all this through http://shellcheck.net/ would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stab in the dark (after reading the comments).  The "$pass" is picking up a newline because the mounts.txt was created in windows and has windows line endings.  Try changing the `echo $pass` line to:

```
echo ---${pass}---
```

and see if it all shows up correctly.

Comment: Ah, windows.  Yes that could do it.  I figured it might be this, but couldn't replicate it myself, but I didn't think of alternate line endings.

Comment: tried changing the echo with no avail, tho it showed me i needed to remove the double quotes in mounts.txt tho by removing the $otherstuff variable, and moving that content to the end of the mount statement, it now writes as 1 line to my output file, and when copied into the terminal now.  Now i have to deal with the script not running through. the script terminates before completing when i run it and i get this error when trying to load through terminal:  line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
    line 30: `done < /path/to/mounts.txt    (updated script in orig question)

Comment: I've just tried running your script, and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Do you use funny passwords?  Put the -o option in "" to prevent ugly expansion problems if $user or $pass contain whitespace or other special characters...  Might as well quote "$path" and "$location" while you're in there ...

Comment: i do have a $ in my password.  i have encased the whole mount command with "" and set it to a variable that gets called.  When i run this from inside the terminal, it works perfect.  It gets the unexpected token issue when i try to run the bash by calling it in terminal or running the actual file in browser.  im going to re-create this file in linux and see if it was an issues starting in windows.

Comment: updated above.  If i paste it into the terminal it works.  if i run it as the .sh i get [[   syntax error near unexpected token `done'     ]]   i ran sudo apt-get update several times, and rechecked several packages manually, to no avail.

Comment: installed dos2unix and now the script is executing.  working out a few bugs but more or less working.  thanks all for looking

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot here that could stand improvement. Consider the following -- far more compact, far more correct -- approach:

```
while IFS=, read -u 3 -r name path user pass empty _; do
  mkdir -p "$location"
  cmd=( mount \
    -t cifs \
    -o "rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=$user,password=$pass" \
    "$path" "$location" \
  )
  printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "${cmd[@]}" # generate a string corresponding with the command
  echo "$cmd_str" >>test.txt          # append that string to our output file
  "${cmd[@]}"                         # run the command in the array
done 3<mounts.txt
```

Unlike the original, this will work correctly even if your path or location values contain whitespace.